# Detecting format/version of ArcMap toolbox using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Is there a way to tell programatically (from the command line) what format a given ArcMap toolbox was saved in - 10.0, 10.1 and so on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the short answer is NO. In arcpy you would typically "Describe" an object to get a handle on its properties. It appears there is no way within arcpy to find out the version the toolbox was saved in. If anyone knows of a way then please shoot me down in flames so I can learn from your wisdom!

But you could fudge it this way:

In ArcCatalog right click on the toolbox and go to properties. In the Description write a description of your toolbox and then right at the end write something like "[Version_10_1]" to indicate its a 10.1 toolbox.

In you python code you could then use something like:

```
obj = arcpy.AddToolbox("C:/temp/testbox.tbx")
description = arcpy.Usage(obj)
if "[Version_10_1]" in description:
  print "10.1 toolbox loaded"
```

Comment: Nice idea, alas doesn't work for me.  My problem is that I keep releasing 10.1 toolboxes by mistake because they save to 10.1 by default when I change them.  10.0 users obviously have problems with this :(  I was hoping to add a step to my build script that checked all the toolboxes were 10.0, shame if it's not possible.

Comment: I've added an [idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E000000056O9IAI) to the ESRI ideas site, so get voting!

Comment: :)  Of course there is a way...  install arcgis 10.0 inside a virtual machine and have my build script test it on that machine.  Alas this is *way* beyond my budget!