# Detecting ArcGIS Pro version using ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

Is there a Pythonic way (e.g. `arcpy`, `os`) to detect which version of ArcGIS Pro is installed on a machine (e.g. 2.8.1 vs 2.8.2)?

I found a similar question for ArcPy in ArcMap ([Detecting format/version of ArcMap toolbox using ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78985)), but am curious if Esri added the functionality. So far, I've looked in [arcpy.Describe](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/describe.htm) and [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version']
```

Strip the `['version']` and you'll get back the entire dictionary of ArcGIS Pro info.

Answer (score 3):

I very much prefer [@KHibma's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/413863/115), but it seems `os.environ` does indeed provide a clue, but not the full story:

```py
import arcpy
import os

environ_details = os.environ
print(environ_details["ESRIACTIVEINSTALLATION"])
### conversely...
print(arcpy.GetInstallInfo()['Version'])
```

The above prints:

```
ArcGISPro2.8
2.8.1
```